# Disable warning JSX props should not use arrow functions react/jsx-no-bind

Tags: reactjs, typescript, lint

I am using TypeScript and inside *.tsx files I am getting the error:

> warning  JSX props should not use arrow functions  react/jsx-no-bind

How do I fix it? I have tried to add options inside `tslint.json`
`jsx-no-lambda": true`, etc. but it did not work.

Comment: That error's from _ESLint_, so changing TSLint probably won't help - https://github.com/jsx-eslint/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/jsx-no-bind.md

Comment: "react/jsx-no-bind": [1, {
      "allowArrowFunctions": true,
      "allowFunctions": true, yes it worked inside eslint
      "allowBind": true
    }],

Answer (score 0):

```
"react/jsx-no-bind": [1, {
  "allowArrowFunctions": true,
  "allowFunctions": true,
  "allowBind": true
}],
```

use inside .eslintrc as per comment